# Как отключить indexing при запуске webstorm?

Tags: phpstorm

При запуске webstorm вешает кампутер из-за этого индексирования, сначала начинает тормозить, а потом вешает наглухо. Подскажите, как отключить это индексирование, оно по умолчанию включено, но, в настройках не могу найти, где это отключается, перерыл все настройки.

Comment: самый простой метод - power saving mode, но я не понимаю, зачем использовать шторм без индексирования. Я бы попробовал написать в техподдержку.

Comment: У меня просто кампутер слабый, на мощных, может, и незаметно индексирует.